# How to use supervisor to process jobs in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

Im using laravel queue to dispach jobs and installed supervisor to hande them. Supervisor processes are working, they are running but not processing my jobs! Meanwhile if I run directly `php artisan queue:listen` jobs are executing!
I created queue-worker in conf.d but still not working.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d
vi laravel-worker.conf
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=5
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Then :wq

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker.conf
```

For more info you can see documentation https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

for the lines `command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3` and `stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel/storage/logs/worker.log`, replace `/var/www/html/laravel` with the path to your project