# How can i run php /dirpath/to/artisan artisan list

Tags: linux, laravel, supervisord

Not any output when run `php /home/directory ... cmd`

I try run supervisor run conf with this command:

```
php /home/example artisan queue:work
```

and after run supervisor, my jobs dosent dispach and my worker log is empty.

I got to linux shell and run this command:

```
php /home/example artisan queue:work
```

but that command dosnt work and I dont recevie any output.

Then i try to run this:

```
cd /home/example and then 
php artisan queue:work
```

and then that work successfully and show to me:

> info processing jobs from the [default] queue

Guys how can i fix that?

Comment: Did you try fully specifying the path to your PHP executable?  `/path/to/php /home/example artisan queue:work`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use supervisor to process jobs in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953381/how-to-use-supervisor-to-process-jobs-in-laravel)

Comment: `/home/example artisan` should most likely be the complete path to `artisan`, so `/home/example/artisan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not really targeting `artisan`.

`artisan` is a file, so a proper command would look like this:

```bash
php /home/example/artisan {whatever artisan command you want to run}
```

That being said, your supervisord configuration should probably mimic the example [from the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#configuring-supervisor):

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/example/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```